# Trying To Pull Out The Latest Date From Another Table

Tags: sql, date, subquery, max

The report I'm creating shows a list of cases where a particular type of letter was sent to them (**'212'**) during a specified date range.

Currently I have a few joins going on to bring out my additional columns, but the area I'm having an issue with is when I try to join the **"Documents"** table with the **"Cases"** table. Before I add the join each case is unique, however as soon as I join the **"Documents"** table there are multiple instances of the same case because within the **"Documents"** table there are many instances of this letter being created per case. I just need to bring out the latest creation date of that letter.

---

SELECT

```
  [casCaseID] as [Case ID],
  [cliForename] + [clisurname] as [Client Name],
  [rusFullname] as [Adviser Name],
  [docDateCreated] as [Date EA Letter Sent],
  [camloan],      
  CASE 
        WHEN isnull(camLoan,0) = 0 or isnull(campurchaseprice,0) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE [camLoan]/[campurchaseprice] 
        END as 'Loan To Value %'


FROM [MPS3].[dbo].[Cases]
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[Clients] on casPrimaryClientID=cliClientID
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[RefUsers] on casAdviserID=rusUserID
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[RefSources] on casSourceID=rsoSourceID
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[CasesMortgage] on casCaseID=camCaseID
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[Documents] on casCaseID=docCaseID and docLetterID =212  
where docDateCreated between @fromDate and @toDate
```

---

I've tried using a subquery on the inner join with 'MAX' but to no avail.

```
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[Documents] 
on casCaseID=docCaseID 
and docLetterID =212 
and docdatecreated = (select max(docdatecreated) 
                      from [MPS3].[dbo].[Documents] 
                      where casCaseID=docCaseID 
                      group by cascaseid)
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT    
  [casCaseID] as [Case ID],
  [cliForename] + [clisurname] as [Client Name],
  [rusFullname] as [Adviser Name],
  MAX([docDateCreated]) as [Date EA Letter Sent],
  [camloan],      
  CASE 
        WHEN isnull(camLoan,0) = 0 or isnull(campurchaseprice,0) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE [camLoan]/[campurchaseprice] 
        END as 'Loan To Value %'   

FROM [MPS3].[dbo].[Cases]
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[Clients] on casPrimaryClientID=cliClientID
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[RefUsers] on casAdviserID=rusUserID
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[RefSources] on casSourceID=rsoSourceID
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[CasesMortgage] on casCaseID=camCaseID
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[Documents] on casCaseID=docCaseID and docLetterID =212  
where docDateCreated between @fromDate and @toDate
GROUP BY
  [casCaseID],
  [cliForename] + [clisurname],
  [rusFullname],
  [camloan],      
  CASE 
        WHEN isnull(camLoan,0) = 0 or isnull(campurchaseprice,0) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE [camLoan]/[campurchaseprice] 
        END
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that worked perfectly. I'm going to check through it to see what was altered.

Thanks again!

Comment: I should have explained. I added a GROUP BY clause. It might look nasty to include the big CASE statement in two places, but it is cached, so not so bad.

Comment: No worries, that's excellent stuff. I couldn't believe I hadn't tried that already. I've saved it for future use just in case!
All the best
Tim

Answer (score 3):

On your join with `MAX()`, try adding the same field checks that are in the join.

```
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[Documents]
   on casCaseID=docCaseID  
  and docLetterID =212  
  and docdatecreated = (select max(docdatecreated)
                          from [MPS3].[dbo].[Documents] 
                         where casCaseID = docCaseID
                           and docLetterID = 212)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
[casCaseID] as [Case ID],
 [cliForename] + [clisurname] as [Client Name],
 [rusFullname] as [Adviser Name],
 (select max(docdatecreated) 
                  from [MPS3].[dbo].[Documents] 
                  where casCaseID=docCaseID 
                        and docDateCreated between @fromDate and @toDate
                  group by cascaseid)
    as [Date EA Letter Sent],
[camloan],      
CASE 
    WHEN isnull(camLoan,0) = 0 or isnull(campurchaseprice,0) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE [camLoan]/[campurchaseprice] 
    END as 'Loan To Value %'

FROM [MPS3].[dbo].[Cases]
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[Clients] on casPrimaryClientID=cliClientID
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[RefUsers] on casAdviserID=rusUserID
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[RefSources] on casSourceID=rsoSourceID
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[CasesMortgage] on casCaseID=camCaseID
inner join [MPS3].[dbo].[Documents] on casCaseID=docCaseID and docLetterID =212
```